# How to solve No module named 'replacers' problem in python?

Tags: python-3.x

i face that problem in my code.Anyone can help me for solving that problem

```
class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in 
                     patterns]
    def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
         s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
      return s

from replacers import RegexpReplacer
replacer = RegexpReplacer()
print(replacer.replace("can't is a contraction"))
```

error is ModulueNotFound error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'replacers'
```

Comment: But do you have that module? Have you installed it? Why do you expect it to be present?

Comment: Did you initialize the replacer folder as python package?

Comment: its not working

Comment: Is that a python module?

Comment: yes it is python module

Comment: Can you share it's link. Did you try `pip install` to install it?

Comment: thank you sir for solving my problem.library was not installed in my anaconda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you install replacer by using the command `pip install replacer`. Secondly, remove `from replacers import RegexpReplacer` from your code. In your code at some place, there is an issue with indentation. Please try given code. This may solve your problem.

```
class RegexpReplacer(object):

   def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):


      self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

   def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
           s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)


      return s


replacer=RegexpReplacer()
print(replacer.replace("can't is a contradicton"))
```