# ImportError: cannot import name 'RegexpReplacer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

This is my code I am trying to user replacer but still get an error, please any idea?? This is my code:

```
import nltk
from replacer import RegexpReplacer
import sys

replacer = RegexpReplacer()
replacer.replace("Don't hesitate to ask questions")
print(replacer.replace("She must've gone to the market but she didn't go"))
```

And this is my error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RegexpReplacer'

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/dmerejkowsky/replacer), it seems that there is no such module `RegexpReplacer`. An example is given, try that. Just use `import replacer`.

Comment: **import replacer
from replacer import RegexpReplacer** i tried this and **import replacer** and this one both give me error

Comment: `import replacer from replacer import RegexpReplacer`, this is NOT a valid statement. what error you got with just `import replacer`?

Comment: sir this is the error ** name 'RegexpReplacer' is not defined**

Comment: i already installed replacer with cmd the problem is RegexpReplacer

Comment: Check the examples on it's website. There is no such module `RegexpReplacer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a `ImportError: cannot import name 'RegexpReplacer'` because there is no module in replacer named RegexpReplacer. Instead create a class named RegexpReplacer with the following code:

```py
import re

replacement_patterns = [
(r'don\'t', 'do not'),
(r'didn\'t', 'did not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot')
]

class RegexpReplacer(object):
   def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
      self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

   def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
           s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
      return s

replacer=RegexpReplacer()
replacer.replace("Don't hesitate to ask questions.")
print(replacer.replace("She must've gone to the market but she didn't go."))
```

Output:

```
She must've gone to the market but she did not go.
```

When you try this code with different strings inside `replacer.replace()`, some of which contain don't, didn't or can't and some of which don't contain any of these three words, *don't*, *didn't* and *can't* will be replaced by *do not*, *did not* and *can not*, and all other strings will not replaced with different strings.

Answer (score 1):

first, try `pip install replacer` and check. If it doesn't work then Remove `from replacer import RegexpReplacer` from your code because that means you can't import it.

You can look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719069/how-to-solve-no-module-named-replacers-problem-in-python)

I hove you will get your answer by looking at the given question

Comment: yea i already installed replacer as the answer said but now still not work for me even after i remove or try some other way